# Elastomeric Paint for Kitchen Floor

Tags: flooring, kitchens

I'm looking for recommendations for coating a kitchen floor.  The floor in question has a plywood subfloor, with 1/6" self leveling compound on top that has hairline cracks, and some epoxy coating on top of that which also has some hairline cracks.  The floor is pretty level, but it flexes slightly, hence the tiny cracks.  Would elastomeric paint work in this case since it is waterproof and flexible?  Perhaps there is some other option that would work?  I'm hoping to avoid planks since they would raise the surface higher than the adjacent flooring.

Thanks

[image: hairline cracks]

Comment: vinyl flooring might be as good match here if your budget is constrained.

Comment: @Jasen Yeah, but I read sheeting is pretty difficult for diyers, especially complicated layouts like mine.  If you meant vinyl planks, I'm trying to avoid raising the surface much more with planks.  I figure some kind of paint would be likely cheapest anyhow.

Comment: Yeah I meant sheeting, you'll need a helper.  I had good success by following the instructions. I used a 1m length of 100mm PVC drain pipe as a roller.

Comment: Vinyl sheet or marmoleum won't add much height. It's tricky to DIY but not impossible.

Comment: @KMJ I'm sure that would work, but I think elastomeric paint would be effective at filling the hairline cracks as well as being cheaper, faster, and easier, though possibly somewhat less long lasting.

Comment: I've painted a floor before. I wouldn't do it again. It really doesn't last.

Comment: @KMJ What kind of paint on what kind of surface?

Comment: 'The paint we could afford' on concrete. It showed wear pretty quickly. I've had the same experience since then with latex on softwood.